# npm hangs, waiting for Node

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I am working in a Windows Environment, with Visual Studio 2015 that came with NodeJS and npm installed.

Because I don't have the admin rights on this machine, I tried to modify the default folder for npm to a personal folder (this was to use npm link).

Anyway. This failed, and I am now unable to use npm. Each command gets stuck when npm calls for node. see below:

```
C:\>npm config get prefix -dd
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\\\node\\node',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\np
m-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'config',
npm verb cli   'get',
npm verb cli   'prefix',
npm verb cli   '-dd' ]
npm info using npm@1.4.9
npm info using node@v0.10.31
npm verb node symlink C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\\node\node
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? ^C
```

Node, and npm, are indeed in the specified path, but the command never ends, and gets stuck, waiting for node.

If that can help, I apparently broke my configuration with this command:

```
npm config set prefix 'C:\Code\npm\'
```

Do you know a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I solved my problem by reinstalling Visual Studio 2015, and installing NodeJS on the side, then adding NodeJS location to VS configuration (in "Configure External Tools")